# Is there a special number different from $e$ and $\pi$ for limit in Mathematics?

Tags: limits, soft-question, pi

Is there a special number other than $e$ and $\pi$ which describes an interesting limit in Mathematics?

I searched, but I could not find it.

Comment: Your question is not well-defined. What do you mean by *"Is there a special number different from e and π for limit in Mathematics"*? For example, there Euler-Macheroni constant is defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\ln n+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)$

Comment: Oops seems like we give the same example. Should I delete the answer??

Comment: I understood, thank you everyone.

Comment: @yanko. It is not a problem to leave it.

Comment: You can edit my question..because english is my second language..I am sorry

Answer (score 4):

There is $\gamma$ for Euler Mascheroni constant see [Link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

Another one is Feigenbaum constant $\delta$ see [Link2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants)

Comment: You're welcome. I found another constant too.

Comment: I edited the post... Feigenbaum constant is denoted by $\delta$ and is equal to $4.669201609...$

Comment: Wow.. Amazing. Thank you for answer.and edit

Answer (score 2):

The "golden ratio", $\varphi$, is the limit of the ratios of successive terms in the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant), i.e., 
$$
ζ(3) = 1.202056903159594285399738161511449990764986292
$$
It is famous in number theory; the values $\zeta(2n+1)$ for the Riemann zeta function are of special interest. $\zeta(3)$ is the limit
$$
\zeta(3)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{1^3}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n^3}\right).
$$