# Total number of mathematical constants

Tags: soft-question, constants

Can we know how many interesting constants exist in all like $\pi$ and $e$?

Comment: Infinitely many. For example, $\zeta(3),\zeta(5),\zeta(7),\ldots $.

Comment: But are all of them interesting. Also, aren't some of them functions of $\pi$

Comment: They are all interesting, because it is not even known whether or not  they are irrational  - with the exception of $\zeta(3)$. And no, you confuse them perhaps with $\zeta(2n)$, which are rational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: Also, the smallest uninteresting constant will be interesting for that reason...

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Yes I was indeed confusing them with $\zeta(2n)$

Comment: "Interesting" is not a binary yes-or-no property. There's a gradation. Some numbers are more interesting than others, but arguably all numbers and certainly all constructable numbers have at least *some* interesting property. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox

Comment: I’d like to discourage users from continuing to downvote this question. The OP can’t delete it because there’s an upvoted answer, and I think the point that it’s too broad has been proven. There’s no reason to continue punishing the OP by deducting rep. Just close it and move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *lots* of interesting constants. See Finch's [Mathematical Constants](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DM25JGC), now in its [second volume](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781316997741). More [here](http://www.mit.edu/~sfinch/constant.html).

Here is the blurb from the first volume:

> *Mathematical Constants*.
>   Famous mathematical constants include the ratio of circular circumference to diameter, π = 3.14 . . . , and the natural logarithmic base, e = 2.178 . . . . Students and professionals usually can name at most a few others, but there are many more buried in the literature and awaiting discovery.
>   How do such constants arise, and why are they important? Here Steven Finch provides 136 essays, each devoted to a mathematical constant or a class of constants, from the well known to the highly exotic. Topics covered include the statistics of continued fractions, chaos in nonlinear systems, prime numbers, sum-free sets, isoperimetric problems, approximation theory, self-avoiding walks and the Ising model (from statistical physics), binary and digital search trees (from theoretical computer science), the Prouhet–Thue–Morse sequence, complex analysis, geometric probability, and the traveling salesman problem. This book will be helpful both to readers seeking information about a specific constant and to readers who desire a panoramic view of all constants coming from a particular field, for example, combinatorial enumeration or geometric optimization. Unsolved problems appear virtually everywhere as well. This is an outstanding scholarly attempt to bring together all significant mathematical constants in one place.

Comment: Are all of them useful in some application?

Comment: They all have some usefulness, almost by definition.

Comment: But are $\pi$ and $e$ special in some sense

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537148/is-there-a-special-number-different-from-e-and-pi-for-limit-in-mathematics

Answer (score 1):

More interesting constant for me is the Euler $\gamma$ constant defined by $$\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty}\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\ln n\biggr)$$
Between many problems actually unsolved is to Know that this constant is irrational or not, therefore its important to know more about this costant.